# show coordinates of an image stored in an array using mathplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, mplcursors

```
    from nptdms import TdmsFile as td  
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import skimage.color
    import skimage.filters
    import mplcursors
    from skimage.feature import corner_harris,corner_peaks
    
    file = 'sample.tdms' 
    with td.open(file) as tdms_file:
     img = tdms_file.as_dataframe()
    cropped_list = []
    sel=cropped_list.append(img.iloc[700:1250,450:1550:])
coords=corner_peaks(corner_harris(sel),min_distance=10,threshold_rel=0.02)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(sel, cmap='gray')
    plotted_points =ax.plot(coords[:, 1], coords[:, 0], color='cyan', marker='o',linestyle='None', markersize=2) 
    mplcursors.cursor(plotted_points, hover=True)
    plt.show(
```

I tried using mplcursors. But nothing is shown on plot when mouse is hovered. The arrow is not showing any coordinates.
I tried by just plotting points without image, still its not showing any coordinates.

[image: plot_withoutimage]

[106 190] [205 167] 249 280] [ 80 301] [343 294] [207 151] [293 300] [ 30 298] [116 301] [290 261] [ 38  81] [295 316] [209 262] [210 285] [205 323] [282 244] [128 158] [255  26] [133 708] [213 243] [214 690] [ 62 241] [ 68 181] [254 692] [ 35  21] [ 74 318] [290 275] [284 178] [185  21] [207 107] [ 25 323] [331  88] [113 273] [157 293] [112 241] [164 323] [250 301] [137  20] [ 35 645] [284 484] [244 317] [ 27 26
9] [356 331] [356  25] [131 279] [206 296] [ 35 490] [139  85] [215 396] [116 150] [139 644] [338 305] [183 330] [140 488] [327 331] [357 550] [187 707] [260 705] [180 646] [282 552] [ 61 554] [113 485] [163 269] [114 642] [287 645] [281 287] [140 241] [327 181] [ 36 552] [242 263] [257  87] [ 52  18] [358  61] [110 397] [359 692] [139 176] [212  23] [140 332] [271 704] [254 359] [ 63  19] [ 37 396] [110  20] [ 65  82] [ 36 176] [211 706] [108 162] [ 65 397] [212 552] [ 62 645] [109 550] [256 240] [283  24] [185 552] [286  86] [186 242] [355 180] [141 550] [ 64 707] [283 704] [285 330] [257 398] [185 398] [285 398] [109 126] [356  89] [ 37 709] [ 64 331] [111 316] [ 35 334] [214 487] [328 241] [119 172] [212  88] [356 244] [253 332] [ 39 240] [328  27] [359 395] [ 77 266] [358 641] [211 642] [110 706] [181 151] [140 396] [110 332] [ 64 489] [182 486] [328 396] [254 485] [195 274] [256 549] [111  83] [328 639] [253 179] [339 270] [206 135] [325 488]]  this is the coords array.
So how can I save the coordiantes in a variable according to shape of image. Only rectangles in first row.
My image is a series of rectangle shaped sensors. Thats why i tried to find the coordinates by mouse click.

Comment: from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import skimage.color
import skimage.filters
from skimage.feature import corner_harris, corner_subpix, corner_peaks

Comment: The input image is  mirrors of a sensor and they are rectangles.  In plot the corners are getting plotted. But the coordinates are not shown. I need to show the corners of rectangle also.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67021006/edit) the  post to add the missing imports and extra information. Did you look into `plt.text()` to write the coordinates as text in the plot?

Comment: The coords array is very large (174,2), how to do this.?

Comment: How do you want the result to look like?  What did you try?  If permanently showing the coordinates makes a too busy plot, [mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/) is an alternative to only show coordinates while hovering with the mouse,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/) automatically create annotations with the x and y positions. Only when you need extra information, you'd need to write a function to change the annotation depending on the selected point.

Here is some code, using a random image to show how it would work:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mplcursors

coords = np.array([[301,557],[301,378],[201,426],[77,58],[243,12],[466,87],[161,75],[302,489],[197,507],[157,400],[131,85],[379,253],[386,525],[215,500],[165,963],[210,381],[308,254],[285,378],[217,628],[77,500],[156,629],[527,67],[514,1010],[234,264],[523,717],[282,630],[523,799],[355,783],[379,474],[353,711],[351,473],[416,719],[232,249],[185,75],[451,409],[130,247],[384,509],[309,473],[202,937],[130,561],[340,549],[310,627],[348,256],[381,869],[258,555],[342,417],[204,393],[385,489],[523,483],[303,784],[448,476],[228,939],[229,559],[454,260],[158,939],[109,521],[158,248],[160,561],[425,319],[129,939],[526,263],[221,389],[236,754],[203,628],[335,492],[453,319],[160,313],[197,76],[420,410],[129,874],[279,250],[130,310],[206,472],[352,1017],[228,508],[117,555],[278,783],[306,937],[424,475],[157,874],[235,407],[78,552],[129,625],[128,781],[423,934],[349,316],[202,781],[378,935],[475,543],[204,547],[391,546],[424,253],[202,251],[170,549],[236,781],[132,471],[75,959],[128,407],[200,356],[309,716],[232,715],[422,629],[274,562],[201,563],[234,471],[149,89],[277,713],[290,12],[236,313],[161,720],[383,626],[350,867],[451,782],[379,783],[450,934],[166,467],[347,626],[450,559],[451,712],[418,875],[379,318],[156,1018],[306,871],[379,408],[278,471],[203,715],[161,782],[203,872],[277,936],[234,874],[348,933],[235,627],[420,561],[438,502],[204,314],[263,499],[279,317],[421,780],[453,627],[334,959],[174,496],[125,500],[131,542],[159,545],[352,499],[79,1012],[417,501],[501,128],[295,340],[215,543],[218,358],[168,1020],[112,504],[158,502]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

img = np.random.rand(550, 1050)
ax.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plotted_points = ax.plot(coords[:, 1], coords[:, 0], color='cyan', marker='o', linestyle='None', markersize=2)
mplcursors.cursor(plotted_points, hover=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: mplcursors to show point coordinates]

Comment: Its still showing any coordinates. I have added edited code and screetshot above.

Comment: %matplotlib notebook, i added this line and its working, thanks

Comment: I am using Juypternotebook.

Comment: With the standard inline matplotlib, the plots are just like still images in Jupyter, without zooming and without showing the coordinates while hovering.

Comment: I have a doubt, why the coordinates shown using mouse are differing from values in Coords array.?

Comment: i have added the image and array. I should find the coordinates according to shape. How to get the coordinates rectangle1, rectangle 2 using code.

Comment: i couldnot use open cv as my imagearray is 2dimensional and was getting 'a img is not a numpy array, neither a scalar' always. The inital file format .tdms is not flexible